# Oracle APEX - no leading zero

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have an app build in Oracle APEX 18.2. Every number field in app have missing leading zero. For example when the number is `0.5`, APEX displays it as `.5`. The problem occurs also in SQL Workshop. In SQL Developer numbers with leading zeros are formatted well, so I think this is problem with Oracle APEX, not with Oracle DB. Is there any global setting for number formatting in APEX?

Comment: I'm curious to know if this is solely a display issue or if this is an issue regarding the data type which is causing errors?  From what I can tell this is a display issue regarding a possible setting as you asked that can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no such a global setting, which means that you'd have to apply some format mask either

- directly (in `SELECT` statement, within the `TO_CHAR` function call), or
- in column's (item's) property

Format mask you might consider is `FM999G990D00` as

- `FM` will remove leading spaces and superfluous trailing zeros
- instead of using explicit `,` and `.` grouping & decimal characters, use `G` and `D` instead

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue adding zeros to numbers, but it was fixed using Function with Oracle Developer

```
select LPAD((max(ID))+1, 6, '0') from Yourtable
```

and call it as a function.

Probably you could use PL/SQL expressions to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently. i fixed it using `to_char(xxx,'FM999G990D00')`

```
SELECT mont.period_name AS PERIOD
     , to_char(ivo.total_overtime,'FM999G990D00')
     , to_char(emho.ACTUAL_TRANSFERRED_HOURS,'FM999G990D00')
     , to_char(emho.actual_recup_days,'FM999G990D00')
FROM .....
```

worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you have a Classic or Interactive Report, in such case:

- Go to page designer and select the column
- Go to the format mask option
- Select the numeric format you wish to have.
- You'll probably get something like 999G999G999G999G990D00
- if it has a 9D00 at the end, change the 9 to a 0

Comment: hi, it's been a while. did it work?